# How do I specify the `nodoc` debian build profile (or any other build profile) to pbuilder-dist?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, debian, packaging, pbuilder

I am trying to create a new set of Qt packages for an older version of Ubuntu (Focal Fossa). I am using a newer release of Ubuntu than the one I am creating packages for, so I am using `pbuilder-dist` which automates the creation of a chroot for the intended distribution. During this process, I have encountered a chicken and egg problem, where the qtbase ubuntu repo (that contains the necessary `debian/control` rules, etc) contains an optional requirement on Qt documentation tools, which themselves depend on the base packages. It appears this is normally worked around by specifying the `nodoc` debian build profile using the environment variable `DEB_BUILD_PROFILES`, which will skip these requirements when performing the pbuilder build, however it doesn't seem to work.

I see the logic in the pbuilder-dist implementation (`filter_restriction_deps` in `/usr/lib/pbuilder/pbuilder-satisfydepends-funcs`) that should be reading the environment variable and filtering out the dependencies that are marked `!nodoc` when `nodoc` is specified, but any means of me specifying `DEB_BUILD_PROFILES` seems to be ignored.

From poking around the various documentation for the debian packaging tools, there should be a way to specify this, but it eludes me. For the moment I have very crudely worked around this by just removing these optional dependencies from the build before issuing the `pbuilder-dist` command line.

Can someone inform me how I can pass a build profile specifier to `pbuilder_dist`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, there is a `--profiles` option to `pbuilder-dist` which fulfills this task. Environment variables do not seem to pass onto the `pbuilder` command that `pbuilder-dist` runs, however the `--profiles` option does.

So, to solve this, I add `--profiles nodoc` on the command line for the `pbuilder-dist` command:

```
pbuilder-dist focal build --profiles nodoc ../qtbase-opensource-src_5.15.9+kkyz-0.1.2.dsc
```